# Flutter Web Page Routing Issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-routes

I need web app with base url as

```
https://example.com/mojjo-test/index.html#/
```

I updated my base url as documented in flutter website:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies

```
 <base href="/mojjo-test/">
```

in index.html

As per flutter documentation Hashing is already enabled

Observations:

1.Flutter web app loads, shows url while loading,

```
    http://example.com/mojjo-test/index.html
```

2.And after some seconds it redirects to

```
    http://example.com/mojjo-test/#/
```

3. Now if we do a refresh, browser will try to load `http://example.com/mojjo-test/#/` and shows an access denied

I am assuming that instead of redirecting to `http://example.com/mojjo-test/#/`, it should redirect to `http://example.com/mojjo-test/index.html#/`

Please provide suggestions on how to achieve it. I would like to keep the initial path to be `https://example.com/mojjo-test/index.html#/`  (with index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advice you commenting out `href` in 'web/index.html' (platform project automatically generated when adding Web). That's how I did it:
https://github.com/maxim-saplin/flutter_web_spa_sample/blob/main/web/index.html

And here's the example of this app working under virtual directory:
https://maxim-saplin.github.io/flutter_web_spa_sample/html/#/

Flutter Web somehow has these silly issues in scaffolding for the web project (`href` in index.html, wrong paths for service worker etc.) - discovered this while playing with GitHub pages.